# Постить новости curl'ом на odnoklassniki.ru

Tags: curl, php

Подскажите, может быть кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой и знает, где глянуть пример. Необходимо постить новости с сайта (есть rss) через curl на страницу одноклассников. С ссылочкой и картинкой.

Comment: Эмс, не совсем понял вопрос, поэтому уточну. Вы хотите парсить сайт одноклассников курлом или наоборот парсить какое-то РСС и выводить в одноклассники?

Comment: Нет, не парсить, отправить запрос так, чтобы на странице одноклассников появился мой текст и моя картинка. Текст и картинка уже получены, про рсс упомянул на слуай, если все таки в однкл есть импорт рсс и я его проглядел и не надо писать велосипед)

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой отправки через API в автоматическом режиме. Дошел до формы одобрения работы приложения (все через CURL), но не могу сымитировать нажатие на кнопку "Подтвердить" и получить параметр code. Кому интересно могу поделиться наработками - по сути дела автоматический постинг в одноклассниках. Застрял на одном шаге.

Comment: **Dal** тоже занимаюсь постингом в ОК через api, пиши icq 214929

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос- как постить новости на страницу одноклассников через их веб -интерфейс? Не разобрался к сожалению в этих финтифлюшках. 
Я бы поковырялся с Вашим вопросом от делать нечего,  но не понял как пользоваться однлклассниками.

Comment: мне интересно) давай пости. сойдет как пример для курла

Answer (score 1):

Ну здесь уже чистое автозаполнение формы курлом, методом POST. Вот кусок кода:

```
 $cont = "Email=email@gmail.com&pass=12345"; // параметры запроса
 ...
 $ch = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // указываем метод отправки данных
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$cont); // данные поста 
 $result=curl_exec($ch);
 if($result) echo("Готово!"); else echo("No...");
 curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но как пользоваться курлом, я знаю. Вопрос был скорее о том, не сталкивался ли именно с кросспостингом на одноклассники и не знаком ли со структурой пост-запросов (там кажется, как и в вк.ком картинка загружается отдельным пост запросом, и отдельным пост-запросом сама новость).

Comment: А у сайта odnoklassniki нет API? Простите, не поверю...

Comment: Для работы с апи одноклассников необходимо создание и одобрение с их стороны приложения.

Comment: любой http снифер расскажет вам куда и что отправляется